# show that $\frac{d}{dt}\langle \gamma(t),\eta(t)\rangle =\langle\gamma '(t),\eta (t)\rangle +\langle \gamma (t),\eta ' (t)\rangle$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inner-products, plane-curves

Let $\gamma,\eta:[a,b]\to \mathbb R^n$ be continuous, differentiable, curves.

show that
$$\frac{d}{dt}\langle \gamma(t),\eta(t)\rangle =\langle\gamma '(t),\eta (t)\rangle +\langle \gamma (t),\eta ' (t)\rangle$$

My answer:

I derived the left hand side using the definition of the derivative

$$\frac{d}{dt}\langle \gamma(t),\eta(t)\rangle = \lim_{\delta \to 0} \frac{\langle \gamma(t+\delta),\eta(t+\delta)\rangle - \langle \gamma(t),\eta(t)\rangle}{\delta}$$

And here I am stuck. I don't see any manipulation I can do with these inner products since they have nothing in common.

Comment: If you write them componentwise, $<\gamma(t), \eta(t)> = \sum_{i=1}^n \gamma^i(t)\eta^i(t)$. So it is just product rule. (I assume that $<\cdot, \cdot>$ is the usual inner product).

Comment: It's better to type langle and rangle instead of < and >.  This makes the expression looks clear and neater than using the keyboard brackets.

Comment: perform a taylor expansion of $\gamma$ and $\eta$ about t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{align*}
  \frac{1}{h}
  & 
  \left[
    \langle \gamma(t+h),\, \eta(t+h)\rangle - \langle \gamma(t),\, \eta(t) \rangle
  \right] \\
  & = 
  \frac{1}{h}
    \left[
      \langle \gamma(t+h),\, \eta(t+h)\rangle - \langle \gamma(t),\, \eta(t+h)\rangle
    \right] 
  + \frac{1}{h}
    \left[
      \langle \gamma(t),\, \eta(t+h)\rangle - \langle \gamma(t),\, \eta(t)\rangle
    \right] \\
  &= 
  \left\langle
    \frac{1}{h}
      \left[
        \gamma(t+h) - \gamma(t) 
      \right],\,
        \eta(t+h)
  \right\rangle 
  +
  \left\langle
    \gamma(t),\,
    \frac{1}{h}
      \left[
        \eta(t+h) - \eta(t)
      \right]
  \right\rangle.
\end{align*}
$$
As $h\to 0$ the first expression goes to
$$\frac{d}{dt} \langle \gamma(t), \eta(t) \rangle$$ 
The last expression  converges to
$$\langle \gamma^{\prime}(t), \eta(t) \rangle + \langle \gamma(t), \eta^{\prime}(t) \rangle
$$
This is done by definition of the derivative, by continuity of $\eta$ and by continuity of the scalar product. The desired equality follows.

Alternatively, in terms of components, $\langle\gamma(t),\eta(t)\rangle=\sum^n_{i=1}\gamma^i(t)\eta^i(t)$. Use the product rule:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\langle\gamma(t),\eta(t)\rangle=\sum^n_{i=1}\frac{d}{dt}(\gamma^i(t))\eta^i(t)+\sum^n_{i=1}\gamma^i(t)\frac{d}{dt}(\eta^i(t))=\langle\gamma^{'}(t),\eta(t)\rangle+\langle\gamma(t),\eta^{'}(t)\rangle$$
Q.E.D.

Comment: Ah I see what you did there! You added and subtracted the same thing, which changes nothing (meaning the equality still stands) but it allowed us to do certain manipulations and get the desired derivatives. well done! thanks!

Comment: @OriaGruber Sure!